# how to implementation Center Location Error (CLE) code

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write the which corresponds to this formula, which one is correct I'm grad for any help 
I load the groundtruth variables and the results too they are in a txt file in this form [x,y,w,h] = 100,22,12,32

[image]

```
filename_groundtruth = 'D:\data_seq\david2\anno\groundtruth_rect.txt';
[groundtruth,delimiterOut]=importdata(filename_groundtruth);
filename_result = 'D:\data_seq\david2\anno\result_rect.txt';
[output_result,delimiterOut]=importdata(filename_result);

Nrg=size(groundtruth,1); %number of images
cle = 0;% The Center Location Error
for i=1 : Nrg
    xg = groundtruth(i,1);
    yg = groundtruth(i,2);
    xr = output_result(i,1);
    yr = output_result(i,2);

    % formula 1
    cle = cle+ (1/Nrg)*sqrt((xg-xr).^2+(yg-yr).^2);

end

cle
```

or

```
filename_groundtruth = 'D:\data_seq\david2\anno\groundtruth_rect.txt';
[groundtruth,delimiterOut]=importdata(filename_groundtruth);
filename_result = 'D:\data_seq\david2\anno\result_rect.txt';
[output_result,delimiterOut]=importdata(filename_result);

Nrg=size(groundtruth,1); %number of images
cle = 0;% The Center Location Error
for i=1 : Nrg
    xg = groundtruth(i,1);
    yg = groundtruth(i,2);
    xr = output_result(i,1);
    yr = output_result(i,2);


 % formula 2
     cle = cle+ sqrt((xg-xr).^2+(yg-yr).^2);
end
cle = (1/Nrg)*cle;

cle
```

Comment: the first one is not correct - the second looks better but would be verified with some good test data